# iTunes arbitrarily cuts imported tracks

Tags: itunes

From some versions, importing tracks to iTunes and playing them, iTunes cuts the song.

I mean: I download it on my Mac then I drag it to iTunes. I write author, title, genre, etc., then I play it. At minute 2:44, iTunes will jump to the end of the song the to the next song. It's not a setting issue because songs are set to end at their end and file plays fine so they aren't corrupted.

Syncing these songs to iPhone, they will have the same issue.

I noticed that it happens just with "high quality" songs (256/320 kbit/s),  low quality songs (as 128 kbit/s downloaded from YouTube) are played fine right to the end.

Played counter get updated.

I think it's an iTunes bug from, around, October 2016. Songs imported before this bug works fine.

Am I the only one having this issue? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Related: [iTunes 10.5.3.3 - songs ending early](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/40589/72620)

Answer (score 1):

This problem borns during importation, importing lot of songs (as an entire album) with just one drag on iTunes will brings iTunes to "overwork" and it will import tracks "cutted". The only solution I've found is to delete this songs from iTunes and reimport them in iTunes one to one and now they play correctly!